# How to use individual url keys for linked (store switcher enabled) Magento CMS pages?

Tags: magento

did some research but didn't come across any solutions or helpless clues regarding this:

In a Magento store CMS pages can be set up for different store views but they are identified by there common url key. That way Magento looks up the correct page when switching stores / languages.

What are best practices or are there recommended extensions to use individual url keys but still keep the pages linked together and recognized by Magento as translations of the same content?

Thanks in advance,
Micha